# CSS can't control nested ul for my navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customise the drop down menu of my navigation bar using `CSS`, the issue i am having is i have a nested `ul` tag this is so that my drop down options come under the home `button`, but unfortunately the drop down is inheriting all the CSS for the top `ul`.

I have tried the following in css using `.main-nav.active2{}` to try and customise the drop down only but no luck, I will attach my HTML and CSS i also have my JS file if needed.

```css
.active3{
                   display: list-item;
                   padding: auto;
                      }
              .active2{
                   width: 100px;
                   position: absolute;
                   z-index: 2;
                   margin-left: auto;
                   font-size:xx-small;

                   }
              .main-nav{

                float: right;
                list-style: none;
                text-decoration-color: none;
                margin-top: 100px;
                /*padding-right: 500px;*/
                      }
              .main-nav li {
                display: inline-block;
                list-style-type: none;
                      }

              .main-nav li a {
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 10px;
                font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
                font-size: 30px;
                      }

              .main-nav li.active a {
                border :1px solid white;
                      } 

              .main-nav li a:hover {
                border: 2px solid white;
                color: pink;
                  }
```

```html
 <div class="Container">
          <body>
          <header>
             <div class="Row"> 
          <ul class="main-nav">
          <li id="Home"><a href="Home">HOME</a></li>
          <ul class="active2">
         <li class="active3"><a>Change Password</a></li>
         <li class="active3"><a>Email Help</a></li>
         <li class="active3"><a>SOS Connect support</a></li>
         <li class="active3"><a>General IT query</a></li>
         </ul>
         <li id="General"><a href="About">GENERAL</a></li>
         <li id="ContactUs"><a href="Contact Us">CONTACT US</a></li>
         <li id="Enquires"><a href="Enquires">ENQUIRES</a></li>
         </ul>
              <div class = "Saber">
           <audio src="Lightsaber.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
              </div>
              </div>

              <div class="Logo">
              <img src="Webtext.png">
              </div>
```

Comment: You have a ul child of a ul element, which isn't allowed. Try wrapping it in a li element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to target the top ul only.

```
.main-nav > li {
  ...
}
```

`.active2 li` won't be affected then.

Comment: Thank you! this sorted it, I am new to web so just finding my way round at the moment thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the selector in a more complete, verbose way. If you experience problems with targeting/locking elements there are a couple of factors to keep in mind.

- Weight based priority, i.e. Id's weigh more than classnames, and so on.
- Usage of !important
- incomplete targeting/selecting of the element, for instance you can target the 'child'-ul from your example by classname

  .active2 { ... }

You can call it by elementname AND classname:

```
ul.active2 { ... }
```

so on and so forth. Try this approach for your styles:

```
  ul.main-nav li ul.active2 {
          width: 100px;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 2;
          margin-left: auto;
          font-size:xx-small;

          }
```